# Getting an NPE using fbconnect module in Play Framework

Tags: java, facebook, playframework

I'm getting the following NullPointerException while trying to use the Play FBConnect module:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at tags.fbconnect.FBConnectTags._button(FBConnectTags.java:26)
        at tags.fbconnect.FBConnectTags$_button.call(Unknown Source)
        at /app/views/main.html.(line:17)
        at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.render(GroovyTemplate.java:203)
```

This seems to be the line where its occurring: https://github.com/rbamba/play-fbconnect/blob/master/app/tags/fbconnect/FBConnectTags.java#L26

Unfortunately I'm not sufficiently familiar with Play modules to debug this myself.

*edit:* In response to a comment, I believe the fbconnect module is correctly configured, since this is being reported earlier in the log:

```
13:12:13,225 INFO  ~ Module fbconnect is available (/home/****/play-1.1.1/modules/fbconnect-0.3)
```

*edit2:* I've actually got it to progress past this point on my local machine, but still getting this NPE on my production server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to Regis Bamba, one of the programmers who works on fb-connect.

I eventually decided to use the fbgraph module instead, and I'd probably recommend this to anyone thinking of using fb-connect because its more powerful, and seems to be better maintained.  Even Regis recommended using it :-)

Regardless, here is what Regis suggested to get rid of the "java.net.URISyntaxException":

The solution is to manually replacing it with its encoded value, before encoding the whole string.

The getAuthUrl() function in FBConnectSession.java should be:

```
public String getAuthUrl(String authCode){
  return "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" +
     WS.encode(id)+"&redirect_uri=" +
     WS.encode(Router.getFullUrl("FBConnect.callback")) +  
     "&client_secret="+WS.encode(secret)+"&code="+WS.encode(authCode.replace("|","%7C"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything specifically wrong with the plugin code. To explain a little of what is going on,

```
// the line of code with the error
String url = Play.plugin(FBConnectPlugin.class).session().getLoginUrl(scope);
```

Lets break this down a little

```
Play.plugin(FBConnectPlugin.class)
```

This line asks Play to return the initialised plugin, from the list of plugins configured within Play. If the Plugin is not set up, then it returns null. This is the most likely reason for the error.

```
.session()
```

This simply gets the session object from the FBConnectPlugin, which is a statically created object, so will not be null.

```
.getLoginUrl(scope);
```

This builds the URL up. This method is not called, otherwise you would see it in the stack trace.

Therefore, the problem is that you have not configured the plugin correctly. Check over the documentation again to make sure why it has a problem. Alternatively, you may want to check out the FbGraph module. I installed this a few days ago, and have a Facebook app up and running already. It is very simple, and the documentation is excellent.

The answer is a little long-winded, but as you said you did not understand how modules worked, I thought it was worth explaining.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I just added something to the question pointing out that the logs report the module being available.  Is FBGraph a substitute for FBConnect?

Comment: Are you using any other plugins? It is possible that other plugins are conflicting with this plugin. Just because the module is installed (which you know because of your output, plus the fact that you are using the FbConnect tag).

Comment: Yes, FbGraph is an alternative. not sure of the exact differences, but take a look at the documentation to learn more. It works well for me

Comment: Nope, this is currently the only plugin I'm using :-/